# How to use Glide with ImageButton?

Tags: android

I have an `ImageButton` that doesn't have any background.
I have a png to be used as an Image for the button. How can I do it with glide (my image is in the `drawable` folder)?

This is my code:

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_main_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
ImageButton ib_main_home;

Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(R.drawable.home)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.home)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(ib_main_home);
```

Comment: When I try it i get this error message: Error:(32, 49) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Drawable

Comment: The question is very good. Actually I would upvote this. Its really hard to find working solution with glide to actually load na image `url` into an `ImageButton`. In this case yes, having a resource drawable is useless to use glide, but what if you have an dynamic image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is in drawable directory, you don't need Glide.set `src` property in xml. remove glide code from activity

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ib_main_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/home"/>
```

You may also set image through activity like below

```
ib_main_home.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.home)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom targets, in particular a `ViewTarget`. Take a look at the [wiki](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets).

Answer (score 0):

in your case:

```
Glide.with(this)
     .fromResource(R.drawable.home)
     .into(ib_main_home);
```

Comment: I got this error message: Error:(35, 17) error: method fromResource in class RequestManager cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: try `.load(R.drawable.home)` instead of fromResource. either way it makes no sense, if you have the image in your drawable then just use it as .placeholder(R.drawable.home) and load the image from url, or just use as src

Answer (score -2):

If the image is in drawable directory, you don't need Glide. Just do:

```
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.home)
```